# How do I get a page to slide down to a div when it loads?

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

So when the page loads, I want it to slide to targeted divs.

```
var todayStory = $('#day2main');
var initialOffset = 550;

$('.storyContainer').load('story.html', function() {
    //story loads fine.
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(todayStory).offset().top-initialOffset}, 1000);
    //doesn't animate to div I indicate.
});
```

Help! Please and thank you!

Comment: Don't you want to use `#` character, without scrolling?

Comment: I'm currently searching for this solution too

Answer (score 3):

Ref: [SMOOTHLY SCROLL TO AN ELEMENT WITHOUT A JQUERY PLUGIN](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2010/01/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin/)

```
 $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#day2main").offset().top
 }, 2000);
```

Comment: Okay, so that works. Thanks. But I have two confounding variables. First, it needs to slide to 550px below the top. I tried just adding ".top+550" but that didn't seem to work. Second, I want to run this on doc ready but it always seems to be off by a few hundred pixels. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `window.location.hash`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.location.hash = '#day2main'; 
});
```

Comment: This will not give sliding effect. It will move the window focus at that particular div

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#day2main').position().top}, 'slow');
```

Comment: does this carry out the animation when the data is being loaded into the div?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('#day2main', '.storyContainer').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

As your `#day2main` is dynamically loaded div so directly you can't give event to that div.
Try this fiddle:

<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/VXr9j/</kbd>